# Telerik OpenAccess OR Mindscape LightSpeed?

Tags: .net, database, orm, lightspeed

I am trying to decide which one to use for complex WinForm project. So any advice, any expirience is welcomed!

Which performs better ? 
Which is easier to learn ?
Which one has better docs and samples ?

...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are both very nice ORMs.  You can't really go wrong here.

I personally love LightSpeed.  I'm using it on my project right now.  It's, in my opinion, the easiest and fastest to get setup, and just works with almost no tweaking in nearly all cases.  (Mindscape, BTW, also has some of the best technical support I've ever seen...)